# How to compare each element of dictionary inside list using loop in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

how to compare each list item of dictionaries from web service response to json data stored in file which have same list item of dictionaries.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  RequestsLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
TestCase1
    # create a HTTP session to a server
    Create Session  country  http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all
    ${response}=  Get Request  country  /
    log list  ${response.content}
    ${data}=  evaluate    json.loads($response.content)    json
    ${RestResponse}=  get from dictionary  ${data}  RestResponse
    ${result}=  get from dictionary  ${RestResponse}  result
    : FOR  ${result}  in  @{result}
    \   log to console  ${result}
    # ${result} display each dictionary item in list
    log to console  \n..Read from file
    ${file}     get file    ${CURDIR}${/}/country.json
    #country file is respose of http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all
    ${filedata}=  evaluate  json.loads($file)  json
    ${RestResponse}=  get from dictionary  ${filedata}  RestResponse
    ${resultfiles}=  get from dictionary  ${RestResponse}  result
    : FOR  ${resultfile}  in  @{resultfiles}
    \   log to console  ${resultfile}
# ${resultfile} display each dictionary item in list
```

Here First and second Loop display each dictionary item , i want to compare each item comes from  `${result}` and  `${resultfile}` which is comes from two different loop.
Do i need to use loop over loop but that is also not clear for me.
and i see another problem `${resultfile}` is coming with unicode for some of the dictionary element

Comment: the easiest solution is to write a  keyword in python that can compare two json objects. Are you open to that sort of solution?

Comment: @Bryan I would prefer to do  in Robotframework, If RF have limitation then i am okay with custom library solution in Python.

Comment: So your question is answered? If so, can you create an answer with the relevant information?

Comment: @ kootstra not yet

Comment: @ A. kootsra , please see solution

Answer (score 0):

I dont find solution in RobotFramework so i just used custom python library to make it work.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  compare.py

TestCase1
    # create a HTTP session to a server
    Create Session  country  http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all
    ${response}=  Get Request  country  /
    ${data}=  evaluate    json.loads($response.content)    json
    ${RestResponse}=  get from dictionary  ${data}  RestResponse
    ${results}=  get from dictionary  ${RestResponse}  result
    log  ${results}
    : FOR  ${result}  in  @{results}
    \   log  ${result}
    # ${result} display each dictionary item in list
    log to console  \n..Read from file
    ${file}     get file    ${CURDIR}${/}/country.json
    #country file is respose of http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all
    ${filedata}=  evaluate  json.loads($file)  json
    ${RestResponse}=  get from dictionary  ${filedata}  RestResponse
    ${resultfiles}=  get from dictionary  ${RestResponse}  result
        log   ${resultfiles}
    : FOR  ${resultfile}  in  @{resultfiles}
    \   log   ${resultfile}
    ${ReverseUnicode}  ChangeFromUnicode   ${resultfiles}
    log  ${ReverseUnicode}
    #compare display all dictionary element which is not matching 
    ${Compare}   compareList  ${ReverseUnicode}   ${results}
    log to console   ${Compare}


    here is Python library code  #compare.py
    import  ast
def ChangeFromUnicode(responselist):
    Returnlist= []
    for listelement in responselist:
        Ndictionary = {}
        for element1, element2 in listelement.iteritems():
            Ndictionary[element1.encode("ascii",'ignore')] = element2.encode("ascii",'ignore')
            Returnlist.append(Ndictionary)
    return Returnlist
def compareList(arg1,arg2):
    list1 = ast.literal_eval(arg1)
    list2 = ast.literal_eval(arg2)
    list3 = []
    for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
        if i != j:
            list3.append(i)
```